# Not able to get $_FILES in laravel 5 while file uploading

Tags: file-upload, laravel-5

I am currently working laravel 5 project. I am trying to do file upload but i found that i am not able to get $_FILES in my controller function. It shows only [] when i write dd($_FILES); in my controller function.
 VIEW CODE:

```
 {!!Form::open(['url'=>'admin','id'=>'MyUploadForm'])!!}
   <input name="fileupload" id="fileupload" type="file" />
   <input type="submit"  id="submit-btn">
 {!!Form::close()!!}
```

ROUTE CODE:

```
Route::get('admin', 'CouponcodefileController@index');
Route::post('admin', 'CouponcodefileController@uploadfile');
```

CONTROLLER FUNCTION:

```
public function uploadfile() {
      dd($_FILES);
    }
```

Please guide in this. Thanks.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#files

Comment: YOu didn't tell laravel you were including a file input, so it won't know to include the approprate `enctype` required for uploads...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> "files" => true

## View

```
{!!Form::open(['url'=>'admin','id'=>'MyUploadForm', 'method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true])!!}
    <input name="fileupload" id="fileupload" type="file" />
    <input type="submit"  id="submit-btn">
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

## Controller

```
public function uploadfile() {
    $file       = \Input::file('fileupload'));
    // $file    = \Request::file('fileupload'));

    $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    dd($file);
}
```

http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

Answer (score 1):

Do it the Laravel way (5.1):

CONTROLLER FUNCTION:

```
public function uploadfile(Request $request) {
    // Laravel 5.0: $file = Request::file('fileupload');
    $file = $request->file('fileupload');    
    dd($file);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files